# PDB state in Oracle 12c RAC

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, rac

Installed two node Oracle RAC. On node 1 opened pdb1 and shows open mode as read and write but on node 2 it's still in mounted state?.

**On Node1**

```
   rlwrap sqlplus / as sysdba

        SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue May 14 04:29:47 2019
        Version 19.3.0.0.0

        Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


        Connected to:
        Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
        Version 19.3.0.0.0

        SQL> show pdbs

            CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
        ---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
                 2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
                 3 PDB1                           READ WRITE NO

        SQL> select CON_ID,DBID,NAME,OPEN_MODE,RESTRICTED from v$pdbs;

        CON_ID        DBID NAME       OPEN_MODE  RES
        ------ ----------- ---------- ---------- ---
             2  1968208496 PDB$SEED   READ ONLY  NO
             3  1212646563 PDB1       READ WRITE NO


SQL> select instance_number,instance_name,instance_mode from v$instance;

INSTANCE_NUMBER INSTANCE_NAME    INSTANCE_MO
--------------- ---------------- -----------
              1 cdbrac1          REGULAR
```

**On Node2**

```
SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 PDB1                           MOUNTED

SQL> select CON_ID,DBID,NAME,OPEN_MODE,RESTRICTED from v$pdbs;

CON_ID            DBID NAME            OPEN_MODE  RES
------ --------------- --------------- ---------- ---
     2      1968208496 PDB$SEED        READ ONLY  NO
     3      1212646563 PDB1            MOUNTED


SQL>  select instance_number,instance_name,instance_mode from v$instance;

INSTANCE_NUMBER INSTANCE_NAME    INSTANCE_MO
--------------- ---------------- -----------
              2 cdbrac2          REGULAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-PLUGGABLE-DATABASE.html)

*pdb_open::=*

[image]

*instances_clause::=*

[image]

To open the PDB on all RAC instances:

`ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE PDB1 OPEN INSTANCES=ALL;`